# JQUERY UI autocomplete doesn't work locally

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, web

I'm trying jquery UI autocomplete function locally on my computer. But it doesn't work at all. Could you suggest me any solutions?

Here is my demo code:

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 var data = ["Adriana","Alessandra","Behati","Candice","Doutzen","Erin","Gisele",
             "Laetitia","Lily","Lindsay","Marisa","Miranda"];


    $(function() {
        $("#search").autocomplete({
                source:data
        });
    });

    </script>

    Search: <input type="text" id="search" />'
```

Comment: What's in your JS console?

Comment: Why in the world are you using such an old version of jQuery and jQuery UI??

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS - they're the latest versions and jQuery 1.10.2 maintains backwards compatibility with old browsers.

Comment: @DaveNewton ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
[Break On This Error]  

})( jQuery );

jquery-ui.js (line 314)
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
[Break On This Error]  

$(function() {

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Including your scripts like this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

won't work locally, since that uses the same protocol as the containing page. In your case, working locally, the protocol is `file://`, and you need it to be `http://`.

Do this instead:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I've just made changes as you suggested, but it still the same - no results showing.

Comment: @SauliusSlavinskas You get the *same* error in the console after correcting the src attribute in *both* script tags?

Comment: @SauliusSlavinskas What happens if you put the URL in your browser URL bar and request them manually? It works fine-ish for me delta the missing CSS.

Comment: @DaveNewton Well, both js loads just fine in URL.

Comment: @SauliusSlavinskas Is what you've posted the entirety of your page? Do you have any other scripts loading?

Comment: @JasonP In addition I'm using autocomplete css styling <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css">. But yeah, that's actually all scripts.

Comment: Somehow I managed to solve the problem. Now it shows results. Unlucky, they are not styled - just a plain list. Here is example - http://s14.postimg.org/o4due2vtd/Screen_Shot_2013_07_30_at_11_44_11_PM.png

Comment: Open the network tab in the dev tools, refresh the page, and look for any errors.

Comment: My bad. Forgot to add rel="stylesheet". Thank you guys once again.

Answer (score 1):

When working on your local machine, reference any external javascripts using `http://` NOT `//`

If you use `//` the `file://` protocol is used.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```